# Code that prints all Prime, Sophie Germain Prime, Twin Prime and Mersenne Prime numbers 1 to 1000000

Tags: methods, boolean

I made a code that can test whether a number is prime, sophie germain prime, twin prime and or mersenne prime. I need to make this into a new code that tests all numbers 0-1000000 and prints out each number belonging to these types. Here is the original program that I need to change

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PrimeMethodsDemo_slm {
    public static boolean isPrime (int n) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (n < 2) isPrime = false;
        else if (n == 2) isPrime = true;
        else for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n) + 1; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    
    public static boolean isSophieGermainPrime (int n) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (n < 2) isPrime = false;
        else if (n == 2) isPrime = true;
        else for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n) + 1 & (i < Math.sqrt(n * 2 + 1) + 1);
            ++i)
        {
            if (n % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    
    public static boolean isTwinPrime (int n) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (n < 2) isPrime = false;
        else if (n == 2) isPrime = true;
        else for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n) & i < Math.sqrt(n + 2) + 1; ++i) {
            if (n % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return isPrime;
    }
    
    public static boolean isMersennePrime (int n) {
        boolean isPrime = true;
        if (n < 2) isPrime = false;
        else if (n == 2) isPrime = true;
        else
            for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n) + 1 & i < Math.sqrt(2 * n - 1) + 1; ++i)
            {
                if (n % i == 0) return false;
            }
        return isPrime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing the `main` method. If you have it in your original code, please add it.

Comment: Also, edit the code so that the original methods are shown. I edited wrongly based on a misunderstood requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by simplifying the *`isPrime(int n)`* method. Below is my simplified solution:

```
public static boolean isPrime (int n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return bigInt.isProbablePrime(100);
}
```

To my understanding, the rest of the methods are by definition true if the numbers are prime to begin with. Therefore, each of these method must check if the given number *`n`* is prime. If the given number isn't prime, you want to return early. Otherwise, you want to continue the computation to see if the given number is Sophie Germain, Twin, or Mersenne prime. Therefore, each of these method should call the *`isPrime(int n)`* before proceeding with the calculation. For example,

```
public static boolean isSophieGermainPrime (int n) {
    return isPrime(n) && isPrime(2*n + 1);
}

public static boolean isTwinPrime (int n) {
    return isPrime(n) && (isPrime(n + 2) || isPrime(n - 2));
}
```

Lastly, you need to include a `main` method that iterates through all the numbers in your range and print out whether a number is prime, Sophie Germain, Twin, and/or, Mersenne prime.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%15s | %6s | %16s | %5s | %9s |%n", "Number", "Prime?", "Sophie Germain?", "Twin?", "Mersenne?");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%15d | %6b | %16b | %5b | %9b |%n", i, isPrime(i), isSophieGermainPrime(i), isTwinPrime(i), isMersennePrime(i));
    }
}
```

Obviously, outputting a million lines to the console might not be the right thing to do here. Instead, I will advice to use a file writer and output each line to a file (unless the specific requirement is to dump to the console). The problem is that, unless you change the size of the buffer used by the console, you will loose a lot of the output.

If you decide to go with my `main` method, the output will look something like this (Mersenne's boolean values shown might be incorrect):

```
Number | Prime? |  Sophie Germain? | Twin? | Mersenne? |
     1 |  false |            false | false |     false |
     2 |   true |             true | false |      true |
     3 |   true |             true |  true |      true |
     4 |  false |            false | false |     false |
     5 |   true |             true |  true |      true |
     6 |  false |            false | false |     false |
     7 |   true |            false |  true |      true |
     8 |  false |            false | false |     false |
     9 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    10 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    11 |   true |             true |  true |     false |
    12 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    13 |   true |            false |  true |      true |
    14 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    15 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    16 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    17 |   true |            false |  true |      true |
    18 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    19 |   true |            false |  true |      true |
    20 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    21 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    22 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    23 |   true |             true | false |     false |
    24 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    25 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    26 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    27 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    28 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    29 |   true |             true |  true |     false |
    30 |  false |            false | false |     false |
    31 |   true |            false |  true |     false |
```

**UPDATE**:
The OP commented "the main method works, but **I only need it to print out the numbers that are prime for each type**..."

A potential way to use my solution and comply with this requirement is to simply instruct your loop to print what you want. For example, to print Sophie Germain primes, simply do something like this:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.printf("%10s%n", "Sophie Germain Primes");
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
        if (isSophieGermainPrime(i)) {
            System.out.printf("%7d%n", i);              
        }
    }
}
```

This will output something like

```
Sophie Germain Primes
      2
      3
      5
     11
     23
     29
     41
     53
     83
     89
    113
    131
    ...
```

The sequence shown above is correct according to [Wolfram MathWorld website](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SophieGermainPrime.html)

Comment: I haven't tested the simplified version of my boolean method you gave me, the main method works, but I only need it to print out the numbers that are prime for each type, I am currently trying to figure out how to do that. Thank you for your help, much appreciated.

Comment: @seb93 the principle is the same. You want to create a base case method for checking if a given number is prime. THEN, you want to use that method to derive whether it is also one of those special cases. For example, a prime `p` is said to be a Sophie Germain prime if both `p` and `2p+1` are prime. Therefore, my method to determine that is `isSophieGermain(int n)` { return isPrime(n) && isPrime(2*n = 1);}` Do you see that? You can use these methods inside a method that determines whether or not to print a number. For example: `if (isSophieGermain(n)) {System.out.print(n);}`

Comment: @seb93 The table form I showed above won't work for Mersenne primes because it will print `true` or `false` based on the exponent `n` and not the actual Mersienne prime. This is because I was using `Math.pow(2, n) - 1` and the loop prints out based on `n`. You have to figure this out as well.