# primenumbers within an interval java

Tags: java, arrays, list, primes, intervals

I have to write a program where you have a lower bound and an upper bound, and the program has to give all the prime numbers inside that interval. I see a lot of these kinds of question, so I understand it a little, but here is where I am stuck.

I have to use these:

public static void main(String[] args) {
public static List getPrimeNumbers(int lowerBound, int upperBound){

I just don't know how to use this to get the right answer.

If my program is called with `getPrimeNumbers(2,17)`, it should return the list:
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17]

EDIT:

```
     public class PrimeNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
getPrimeNumbers(int lowerBound, int upperBound);
}

public static List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    int lowerBound, upperBound,count = 0, i, j;
    for (int i = lowerBound; i <= upperBound; i++)
    {      for (j = 2; j< i; j++)
    {           if (i % j == 0 )
    {       count = 0;
                break;
    }
    else
    {
        count = 1;

    }
    if(count == 1)


    return // new ArrayList<>();
```

this is what I have right now

EDIT:
I understand!! thankyou for all your inputs!!

Comment: you cannot put a method inside a method

Comment: It looks like your task is to implement the method `getPrimeNumbers` (which, by the way, should be _outside_ of `main`). Have you attempted it and got stuck somewhere? If so, show us your code and where you got stuck.

Comment: Use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to find numbers up to the upper bound, and ignore any below the lower bound.

Comment: @DavidConrad the Sieve of Eratosthenes is good only for small numbers. If your intervals are 1000000000000 to 1000000000100, you may run out of memory creating such a large array.

Comment: @k314159 OP mentions an interval of 2 to 17, and it appears to be a homework assignment, so I rather doubt that is an issue here.

Comment: You're using the most obscure indentation style I've ever seen!

Answer (score 1):

Use [isProbablePrime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)), it is faster than any implementation that you will write.

Comment: This method doesn't give you 100% certainty. Also, it's not faster than a hand-coded solution if you're doing it for small numbers. Using a BigInteger is overkill when all you need is a primitive int.

Comment: You can pass "certainty" of 100 for example, and the probability for false positive is 2^-100, I wouldn't worry about it. Personally, I prefer to use library tested code than my own implementation for such scenarios, and I believe the performance is good, but you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Do a for loop in inside the function

```
public static List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(int lowerBound, int upperBound){
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumber = new ArrayList<>()
    // loop over all numbers in the range and add the number to primeNumber list if it is a prime.
    for (int i = lowerBound, i <= upperBound, i++){
        if isPrime(i){
            primeNumber.add(i);
        }
    }
    return primeNumber;
}

// function to check if a number is prime
public static boolean isPrime(int num){
    boolean flag = false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= num / 2; ++i) {
        // condition for nonprime number
        if (num % i == 0) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For, smaller numbers, you can get away with Sieve of Eratosthenes. For larger ones, this method won't work...

```
private static boolean sieve[];

private static void eratosthenesSieve(int maxN)
{
     sieve = new boolean[maxN+1];
     
     Arrays.fill(sieve, true);//sets all elements of the given array to true
     sieve[0] = false;// 0 isn't prime
     sieve[1] = false;// 1 isn't prime
     
     for (int i = 2; i <= maxN; i++) {//loop starts at 2 because we already know that 0 and 1 are false...
         if (sieve[i]) {//checks if the current number is prime
              for (int j = i*2; i <= maxN; j+=i) {
                  sieve[j] = false;//sets the multiples of current prime number to false
              }
          }
     }
}

public static void main(String... args)
{
     int min = 0, max = 0;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     
     System.out.println("Enter the range of Prime numbers seprated with a space");
     min = sc.nextInt();
     max = sc.nextInt();
     
     eratosthenesSieve(max);
     do{//loop prints in descending order, if you want ascending change the condition to min++<max, check sieve[min] instead of sieve[max] and print min instead of max
         if(sieve[max]){
             System.out.println(max);
         }
     }while(max-->min);//loop is min and max inclusive if you want only max exclusive, change this to while loop with same condition, if you want both exclusive change this to while loop with --max>min condition
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap a method called `isPrime(int)` where I will call `BigInteger#isPobablePrime()` as suggested by @[barakugav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531300/2851311). I provided an answer [in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67258876/2851311) where you can see this in action.

The reason for this approach is so that can establish a method for your best case that can be reused for method that check for other type of primes; like Sophie Germain primes.

```
public boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n < 2) return false;
    BigInteger bigInt = BigInteger.valueOf(n);
    return bigInt.isProbablePrime(100);
}

/*
 * A prime p is said to be a Sophie Germain prime if both p and 2p+1 are prime
 */
public boolean isSophieGermainPrime(int n) {
    return isPrime(n) && isPrime(2*n + 1); // reusing my base method to implement a new variant
}
```

The same can be said to calculate prime numbers in range...

```
public List<Integer> getPrimeNumbers(int min, int max) {
    public List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int n = min; n <= max; n++) {
        if (isPrime(n)) {
            primes.add(n);
        }
    }
    return primes;
}
```

**UPDATE**:
I would change the data types of the arguments from `int` to `long`. This allowed me to calculate the first nine Marsenne primes in range `mersennePrimeForRange(1, 1000000000)`

```
/*
 * A Mersenne prime (Mn) is a prime number that is one less than a power p of two
 * where exponent p must be prime as well.
 */
public static void mersennePrimeForRange(long min, long max) {
    for (long p = min; p <= max; p++) {
        if (isPrime(p)) {
            long mn = (long) Math.pow(2, p) - 1;
            if (isPrime(mn)) {
                System.out.printf("Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = %d is %d%n", p, mn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 2 is 3
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 3 is 7
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 5 is 31
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 7 is 127
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 13 is 8191
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 17 is 131071
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 19 is 524287
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 31 is 2147483647
Mersenne prime Mn for exponent p = 61 is 2305843009213693951
```

Comment: The `certainty` argument is not a percentage. Also, `isProbablePrime` cannot let you even express 100% certainty.

Comment: @k314159 When did I state that the argument was a percentage?

Comment: You didn't, but the fact you passed 100 to it seemed to imply it. It's close enough to 100% certainty though.

Comment: @k314159 that was an assumption on your part and an incorrect one at that. ;)  That was part of code I wrote where I was experimenting with factors of 10 to test performance when calculating using large integer values.